# My whole test suite crashes every time when one of the tests failed

Tags: testng, dataprovider

when I start my whole test suite it works well till tests with @DataProvider start executing. Especially when Asserts crash. The suite stops executing and don't go to the next test.

Here's the text from the console:

There was an error in the forked process
class Test.ExperimenthalTest cannot be cast to class Base.BaseTest (Test.ExperimenthalTest and Base.BaseTest are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

My pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>allureTestNGExample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.plugin.validation>DEFAULT</maven.plugin.validation>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Compiler plug-in -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Added Surefire Plugin configuration to execute tests -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.6/aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar"
                    </argLine>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <allure.results.directory>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</allure.results.directory>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>1.9.6</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
            <version>2.24.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.15.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

My testng.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="All Test Suite">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="io.qameta.allure.testng.AllureTestNg"/>
        <listener class-name="Base.TestListener"/>
    </listeners>
    <test name="E2E">
        <classes>
            <class name="TestE2E.BuyBackPackTest">
                <methods>
                    <include name="buyBackPack"/>
                    <include name="buyBackPack2"/>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="MainPageGoodsTests">
<classes>
            <class name="Test.AllGoodsPageTest">
                <methods>
                    <include name="bikeLightHeaderTextTest"/>
                    <include name="backPackHeaderTextTest"/>
                    <include name="boltTshirtHeaderTextTest"/>
                    <include name="fleeceJacketHeaderTextTest"/>
                    <include name="whiteShirtHeaderTextTest"/>
                    <include name="hoodyHeaderTextTest"/>
                </methods>
            </class>
</classes>
</test>

    <test name="MainPageEveryGoodTests">
        <classes>
            <class name="Test.EveryGoodTest">
                <methods>
                    <include name="bikeLightPageTextTest"/>
                    <include name="backPackPageTextTest"/>
                    <include name="boltShirtPageTextTest"/>
                    <include name="fleeceJacketPageTextTest"/>
                    <include name="whiteShirtPageTextTest"/>
                    <include name="hoodyPageTextTest"/>
                </methods>
            </class>
            </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="DataProviderTests">
        <classes>
            <class name="Test.ExperimenthalTest">
                <methods>
                    <include name="theFirstDataProviderTest"/>
                    <include name="theFirstDataProviderTest2"/>
                    <include name="theFirstDataProviderTest3"/>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="LoginTests">
        <classes>
            <class name="Test.LoginPageTest">
                <methods>
                    <include name="enterTest"/>
                    <include name="enter2Test"/>
                    <include name="autorize2Test"/>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="OtherTests">
        <classes>
            <class name="Test.ProviderResolveTest">
                <methods>
                    <include name="theFirstDataProviderTest2"/>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

My Base class:

```
public abstract class BaseTest {
    private WebDriverWait wait2;
    private WebDriverWait wait5;
    private WebDriver driver;
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://www.saucedemo.com/";

    @BeforeMethod(description = "Browser startUp")
    protected void beforeMethod() {
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*", /*"--headless",*/ "--window-size=1920,1080");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        getDriver().get(BASE_URL);
    }

    @AfterMethod (description = "Browser tearDown")
    protected void afterMethod() {
        driver.quit();
    }
    protected WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }
    protected WebDriverWait getWait2() {
        if (wait2 == null) {
            wait2 = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), Duration.ofSeconds(2));
        }
        return wait2;
    }
    protected WebDriverWait getWait5() {
        if (wait5 == null) {
            wait5 = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), Duration.ofSeconds(5));
        }
        return wait5;
    }
}
```

My testListener:

```
public class TestListener extends TestListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        Object currentClass = result.getInstance();
        WebDriver driver = ((BaseTest) currentClass).getDriver();
        takeScreenshot(driver, result.getName());
        saveScreenshotToAllure(result.getName());
    }

    private void saveScreenshotToAllure(String screenshotName) {
        try {
            File screenshot = new File("./screenshots/" + screenshotName + ".png");
            if (screenshot.exists()) {
                byte[] screenshotContent = Files.readAllBytes(screenshot.toPath());
                Allure.getLifecycle().addAttachment(screenshotName, "image/png", ".png", screenshotContent);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void takeScreenshot(WebDriver driver, String screenshotName) {
        try {
            TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
            File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File("./screenshots/" + screenshotName + ".png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My tests with @DataProvider:

```
@DataProvider(name = "data2")
    public Object [][] data () {

            return new Object[][]{
                    {""},
                    {"a"},
                    {"al"},
                    {"ale"},
                    {"aaaaaaaaaaaaalex"},
                    {"aaaaaaaaaaaaaalex"},
                    {"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaalex"},
                    {"alex!"},
                    {"alex@"},
                    {"alex#"},
                    {"alex$"},
                    {"alex%"}
            };
    }

@Epic(value = "Проверки полей")
    @Feature(value = "Данные покупателя")
    @Story(value = "Проверки полей страницы заполнения данных юзера")
    @Severity(value = SeverityLevel.NORMAL)
    @Description(value = "Проверка поля LASTNAME на граничные значения и спецсимволы ....")
    @Test(dataProvider = "data2", description = "Проверка поля LASTNAME")
    public void theFirstDataProviderTest2(String option) throws IOException {

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.saucedemo.com/");

        WebElement loginField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='user-name']"));
        WebElement passField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='password']"));
        WebElement submitButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login-button']"));

        Allure.step("Autorization");
        loginField.sendKeys("standard_user");
        passField.sendKeys("secret_sauce");
        submitButton.click();

        Allure.step("Going to the backpack's page");
        WebElement backPackTitle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'inventory_item_name')][contains(text(),'Sauce Labs Backpack')]"));
        backPackTitle.click();

        Allure.step("Adding the backpack to the cart");
        WebElement addBackPackToCart = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@data-test='add-to-cart-sauce-labs-backpack']"));
        addBackPackToCart.click();

        Allure.step("Going to the cart");
        WebElement backPackCartIcon = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='shopping_cart_link']"));
        backPackCartIcon.click();

        Allure.step("Going to the checkout page");
        WebElement chekoutButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@data-test='checkout']"));
        chekoutButton.click();

        final String buyersInfoPageTitle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"header_container\"]/div[2]/span")).getText();
        Allure.step("Checking that the checkout info page is existed");
        Assert.assertEquals(buyersInfoPageTitle, "Checkout: Your Information");

        Allure.step("Filling the field NAME");
        WebElement firstNameField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='First Name']"));
        firstNameField.sendKeys("Tom");

        Allure.step("Filling the field LASTNAME");
        WebElement lastNameField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Last Name']"));
        lastNameField.sendKeys(option);

        Allure.step("Filling the field POSTCODE");
        WebElement postCodeField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Zip/Postal Code']"));
        postCodeField.sendKeys("123456");

        Allure.step("Clicking on the submit button");
        WebElement submitButtonCheckout = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']"));
        submitButtonCheckout.click();

        Allure.step("Checking that the checkout overview page is existed");


        String checkoutTitle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='title'][contains(text(),'Checkout: Overview')]")).getText();
        Assert.assertEquals(checkoutTitle,"Checkout: Overview");

        driver.quit();
    }
```

I don't know how to resolve this problem so my turns to resolve were comlicated.
I tried to change catch (IOException e) into catch (IOException | NoSuchElementException e) in test lestener but it didn't help.

These tests with @DataProvider work well in case if I start it singly. But they don't work well if I try to use it with the whole suite.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the complete stacktrace of the error ? I also noticed that you have put in different values in terms of JDK.  You are setting it as `17` in `<maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>` and you are setting it as `11` in the `compiler plugin` entry. Please fix this as well.

Comment: Thx for replying. I've already resolved this problem partly. My TestLestener refers to BaseTest class. But the class with dataprovider tests weren't extended from that one. I did extend and now it works.